# Div position centering

Tags: css

I have need to position div with id="center_dv" on center of the div with id="wrapper_dv" and to div wrapper_dv be on center of body. How can I do it ?

```
 <body>
    <div id="wrapper_dv">
        <div id="center_dv">
            <p>some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

the most common way is to give the `div` a `width`, and to use `margin-left` and `margin-right: auto`

If your `div` is normally having top and bottom margin as 0, then it can be

```
#center_dv { width: 300px; margin: 0 auto }
#wrapper_dv { width: 600px; margin: 0 auto }
```

(Giving margin 1 length means apply it to all 4 sides, top, bottom, left and right.  Giving margin 2 lengths means apply the 1st length to top and bottom, and the 2nd length to left and right.)